# How to implement if (t1.ID=t2.ID) returned nothing do the stuff

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have two tables one *table1* containing `ID, NAME` another *table2* is only `ID`.

I want to have all `IDs` in *table2* and return `ID` in *table2* and `NAME` in *table1* but I also want `IDs` in *table2* which is not exist in *table1* and just print `ID`, `- - -`.

How do I implement `if (table1.ID=table2.ID)` returned nothing do the stuff as well and print `ID` with `null` `NAME` *column*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want a `LEFT JOIN` (it really helps if definitions of tables, sample data and expected results is included in the question):

```
SELECT t2.id, coalesce(t1.name, '---') as name
     , CASE WHEN t2.id = t1.id THEN 'EQUAL' ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' END 
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```

coalesce returns the leftmost column that is `not null`, in this case `t1.name` if it's `not null` and `---` otherwise. If you want to avoid a `join` (not sure why) you can use a sub select:

```
SELECT t2.id, coalesce((SELECT t1.name
                        FROM t1
                        WHERE t2.id = t1.id), '---') as name
FROM t2;
```